# Release XCode 8 build in July 2018

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, release, submission

Apple says:

> Xcode for future app deliveries." WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version
>   Issue. In July 2018, iOS app updates submitted to the App Store will
>   need to be built with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode
>   [9.0] or later. Make sure to update Xcode for future app deliveries."

However, I cannot find in the documentation that if you submitted an XCode 8 build before July 2018 and it was approved, can you still release it in July?

(Note that Apple only says it affects submission, I wonder if it also affects releases.)

Comment: as long as it is approved by the deadline it should be fine. if it gets rejected for some other reason then you would need to submit a new build, which would then need to be using the updated SDK